# array accesses in Radix Sort

Tags: radix-sort, arrayaccess

I am studying radix sort and I can't understand why array accesses in radix sort is `11N+4R+1`.
The following is radix sort code written in Java.

```java
int n = a.length;
String[] aux = new String[n]; //N
int[] count = new int[R + 1]; //R+1

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    count[a[i]+1]++; } //why 3N?

for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
    count[r + 1] += count[r]; } //3R

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    aux[count[a[i]]++] = a[i]; } //3N(?)+N+N = 5N

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = aux[i]; }  //2N
```

`count[a[i]+1]++;` is equal to `count[a[i]+1]=count[a[i]+1]+1;`. I think each `count[a[i]+1]` has 2N array accesses so the total is 4N. If you look at the third for loop, `a[i]` is also duplicated at both sides in `aux[count[a[i]]++] = a[i]` but the right one is just counted one array access.  Why does `count[a[i]+1]++` count to 3N?

Comment: Which source are you using that's giving a value of 11N + 4R + 1? That would have to be specific to a particular implementation of radix sort, rather than to the more abstract "radix sort" algorithm.

Comment: This is from my school class material. I searched more specific code and explanation about this, but I still don't understand. https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2180073